# Modern language support += but not &&=

Tags: operators, language-design, shortcut

Most (but I only actually know a small number so lets not get picky on that point) high level languages support multiple different assignment operators.

```
a += 5;  // increment a and assign result beack to a.
```

But none (that I have looked at (again a small number)) seem to support the &&= operator.
The reason I ask I recently saw this:

```
// simplified.
bool x = false;


x = x && testA(); // perform test A/B/C/D stop on first failure.
x = x && testB();
x = x && testC();
x = x && testD();
```

And I was wondering why we could not use:

```
x &&= testA(); // perform test A/B/C/D stop on first failure.
x &&= testB();
x &&= testC();
x &&= testD();
```

The reason being that &&= is not supported in C/C++ which made we think why.

Is there a logical (no pun intended) reason why the language supports all the other major operators with an assignment form but not the &&= or ||=

I have a vague recollection for an argument against these, but google and SO searches are hard when your search term is '&&=' and as a result I found nothing.

Comment: I had _exactly_ this thought today, because in lua, `&&` is the word `and`, so I wondered how they did `&&=`, and realized that there is no `&&=`, in lua or in most languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` and `||` are special in the sense that they are, in most languages, the only constructions that provide short circuiting evaluation so it kind of makes sense for them to be treated differently from the normal, non short-circuiting, operators when it comes to the abbreviated forms. The easiest way to avoid the confusion of `&&=` short-circuiting or not is not including it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Perl supports this.  It is very handy to be able to write:

```
$x ||= $defaultX;
```

Comment: I thought Perl supports every possible combination of every operator and everything else in the world?

Answer (score 1):

The first reason is, that the languages allow you to reach your goal using the "verbose" form. After that it is frowned upon adding operators for each and every unusual case. Part of the reason is, that the language designer has to decide about operator precedences wisely. This is not as easy as it looks like - take C as an example which messed up intuitive precedences on `&`, `|`, `&&` and `||`.

The second reason is, that most modern languages support some form of exceptions. Your case can be easily rewritten by using exceptions with the added bonus, that information about the failure can be passed up to the caller more easily.

Therefore the need for special operator like this is quite small.

Oh, I nearly missed the most important reason: C does not have them. What this means is best described in [A Brief, Incomplete, and Mostly Wrong History of Programming Languages](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/05/brief-incomplete-and-mostly-wrong.html):

> 1970 - Niklaus Wirth creates Pascal, a procedural language. Critics
>   immediately denounce Pascal because it uses "x := x + y" syntax
>   instead of the more familiar C-like "x = x + y". This criticism
>   happens in spite of the fact that C has not yet been invented.
>
> 1972 - Dennis Ritchie invents a powerful gun that shoots both forward
>   and backward simultaneously. Not satisfied with the number of deaths
>   and permanent maimings from that invention he invents C and Unix.

This simply shows that C is still an attractor you cannot escape.

Comment: I still don't get why there is a "mostly wrong" in that title. :P

Answer (score 0):

Unlike += and friends, &&= doesn't map to a single hardware instructions. It's a kind of test-or-clear.

Answer (score -1):

When would you ever really need this? Generally, when you do boolean operations, you're not updating values, but rather computing something for a one-time operation. Your example is not very realistic; there aren't many cases in which you'd really do it.

Also, in all languages that I can think of augmented assignment only exists for bitwise and arithmetic operations, never boolean operations.

Comment: It's very handy when the left-hand side is not boolean, but has *truthiness*.